# Ajax works for 1 parameter. How to pass two or more?

Tags: ajax, json, parameters

Here is my code below that works, but passess only the first parameter. But I need two. I think JSON should be used for that purpose. I've tried, but still have no luck. Here is my working code that sends `name`. This function does NOT pass `password`

```
var name     = $('#name').attr('value');//the value from input type name
var password     = $('#password').attr('value');//the value from input type password
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "index/success",
 data: "name="+ name +"&amp;password="+ password,
 success: function(){
   $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
 }
});
```

From the other side I use method 
`$model->values ( $_POST );`
 so that 
`$model->name` is defined and is what I actually sent. 
But, 
`$model->password` is empty.

P.S. Password should be crypted, I know that. That's a simplified example just to ask about using JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data: { name: name, password : password} ,
```

and let jQuery worry about encoding that for the request.

Comment: This   data: { name: name, password : password} ,   works like a charm. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I fixed the typo in my question. Thank you so much!